adf collection reference with 1 row
Using ADF Collection reference we transfer this into json format .
whilst this works for muliple records . It fails with 1 xml record.
The error is ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidPathForCollectionReferenceNode,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Invalid json path '$['file-data']['files']['row']' for collection reference node
The sample file for 2 rows that works is below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<file-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <files>
        <row record="01">
            <FilePath>/MYDIRECTORY/MYTest/</FilePath>
            <ValidatedBy>Joe Blogg</ValidatedBy>
        </row>
        <row record="02">
            <FilePath>/MYDIRECTORY/MYTest01/</FilePath>
            <ValidatedBy>Jose</ValidatedBy>
        </row>
    </files>
</file-data>

This does not work .
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<file-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <files>
        <row record="01">
            <FilePath>/MYDIRECTORY/MYTest/</FilePath>
            <ValidatedBy>Joe Blogg</ValidatedBy>
        </row>
    </files>
</file-data>

sample output required
{"FilePath":"/MYDIRECTORY/MYTest/","ValidatedBy":"Joe Blogg"}


This has been reported here too Azure Data Factory - Collection reference failing when only 1 record
any suggestions


When defining collection reference as $['file-data']['files']['row'] if there is only 1 row it treats as object not as array that may be the reason to get above error. To get your required output follow below procedure:
Go to mapping make Collection reference as empty, enable Advanced editor  and Define columns as below:

Filepath --> $['file-data']['files']['row']['FilePath']

ValidatedBy --> $['file-data']['files']['row']['ValidatedBy']



The you will get the Json as shown below:
{"FilePath":"/MYDIRECTORY/MYTest/","ValidatedBy":"Joe Blogg"}


update:
Use lookup activity to read the file. Count the rows in file using @length(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]['file-data'].files.row)
After reading the file add if activity to the lookup activity with condition:
@greater(length(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]['file-data'].files.row),1)
To check the row count is greater than 1 or not. If true add copy activity with required source with below mapping:

If false add copy activity with required source with below mapping:

Then it will work according to the row count. Here is the pipeline Json for your requirement:
{
    "name": "pipeline4",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "XmlSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "XmlReadSettings",
                            "validationMode": "none",
                            "namespaces": true
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Xmlmulr",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "If Condition1",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@greater(length(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]['file-data'].files.row),1)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifFalseActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1_copy1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "XmlSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "XmlReadSettings",
                                        "validationMode": "none",
                                        "namespaces": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "JsonSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "JsonWriteSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "mappings": [
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "path": "$['file-data']['files']['row']['FilePath']"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "path": "FilePath"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "path": "$['file-data']['files']['row']['ValidatedBy']"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "path": "ValidatedBy"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "collectionReference": ""
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Xml1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Json1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "XmlSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "XmlReadSettings",
                                        "validationMode": "none",
                                        "namespaces": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "JsonSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "JsonWriteSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "mappings": [
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "path": "['FilePath']"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "path": "FilePath"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "path": "['ValidatedBy']"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "path": "ValidatedBy"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "collectionReference": "$['file-data']['files']['row']"
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Xmlmulr",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Json1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "rowcount": {
                "type": "Integer"
            },
            "row": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "r1": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}


I was looking for a dynamic solution that will handle both the scenarios i.e. two rows and one row . Whilst the two rows works the one does not work.  Apologies for the confusion

@nick leeson updated my answer, please check it once. Let me know if it is reaching your requirement or not.
